Right align text next to price
In trading view, you can add a horizontal line, and then add text to it. You can choose vertical and horizontal placement. When you choose to align right it sits on the line on the far-right side of the screen right next to price.
I cannot figure out how the heck to do that in pine script. I can place it on the current bar, the far right bar, and add offsets. But I want the x pos to just sit at the far-right side right next to price.
This is an example. Thanks to anyone who could figure this one out!


See the recommendations in the answer to this question link

Thanks, but nope. not the same thing.
